# How to apply Custom Paging in JQGRID

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

I have a Jqgrid, In my MVC view, there is no problem in displaying the data in the grid. But I want to apply the custom paging in the grid, so  i have created the method in my controller which takes two parameters (pageNumber and rowSize) and returns the data based on the these two parameters.
**Now my question is that how can i send these two property of grid to the controller and get the changes reflected on the grid.**

Note: i also tried to send the value of rowSize using ajax on the button click but after executing the code in the server there is no changes in the grid(as i expected).

**View:**

```
<table id="jQGridDemo">
</table>
<div id="jQGridDemoPager">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery("#jQGridDemo").jqGrid({

        datatype: "json",
        colNames: ['Id', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Last 4 SSN', 'Department',
                'Age', 'Salary', "Address", 'Marital Status'],
        colModel: [
                 { name: 'ID', index: '_id', width: 20, stype: 'text' },
                 { name: 'FirstName', index: 'FirstName', width: 150 },
                 { name: 'LastName', index: 'LastName', width: 150 },
                 { name: 'LastSSN', index: 'LastSSN', width: 100 },
                 { name: 'Department', index: 'Department', width: 80, align: "right" },
                 { name: 'Age', index: 'Salary', width: 80, align: "right" },
                 { name: 'Salary', index: 'Salary', width: 80, align: "right" },
                 { name: 'Address', index: 'Address', width: 150, sortable: false },
                 { name: 'MaritalStatus', index: 'MaritalStatus', width: 100, sortable: false }
               ],
        rowNum: 10,
        loadonce: false,
        rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
        pager: "#jQGridDemoPager",
        height: "100%",
        sortname: 'ID',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "desc",
        caption: "List Employee Details",
        url: '/Home/Records'
    });

    $(".ui-pg-input").click(function () {

        alert(this.value);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: window.location + "Home/Records",
            data: {
                pageNumber: this.value
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert("ajax call completed");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Something went Wrong");
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
 public JsonResult Records(int pageNumber=3, int rowSize = 5)
 {
     // code for custom paging
     return json;
 }
```

**JSON Returned from Server:**

> [{"ID":1,"FirstName":"Alan","LastName":"Donald","LastSSN":"123","Department":"Bowler","Age":"44        ","Salary":"1000000   ","Address":"South Africa","MaritalStatus":"Married   ","EntityState":2,"EntityKey":{"EntitySetName":"tbl_Details","EntityContainerName":"JQGridDBEntities","EntityKeyValues":[{"Key":"ID","Value":1}],"IsTemporary":false}},{"ID":2,"FirstName":"Donald","LastName":"Duck","LastSSN":"345","Department":"Actor","Age":"98        ","Salary":"2000000   ","Address":"USA","MaritalStatus":null,"EntityState":2,"EntityKey":{"EntitySetName":"tbl_Details","EntityContainerName":"JQGridDBEntities","EntityKeyValues":[{"Key":"ID","Value":2}],"IsTemporary":false}},{"ID":3,"FirstName":"Virat","LastName":"Kohli","LastSSN":"111","Department":"Batsman","Age":"28        ","Salary":"1000000   ","Address":"India","MaritalStatus":"Unknown   ","EntityState":2,"EntityKey":{"EntitySetName":"tbl_Details","EntityContainerName":"JQGridDBEntities","EntityKeyValues":[{"Key":"ID","Value":3}],"IsTemporary":false}},{"ID":4,"FirstName":"MS","LastName":"Dhoni","LastSSN":"112","Department":"Captain","Age":"31        ","Salary":"9000000   ","Address":"India","MaritalStatus":"Married   ","EntityState":2,"EntityKey":{"EntitySetName":"tbl_Details","EntityContainerName":"JQGridDBEntities","EntityKeyValues":[{"Key":"ID","Value":4}],"IsTemporary":false}},{"ID":5,"FirstName":"Sachin","LastName":"Tendulkar","LastSSN":"113","Department":"Superman","Age":"40        ","Salary":"90000000  ","Address":"India","MaritalStatus":"Married   ","EntityState":2,"EntityKey":{"EntitySetName":"tbl_Details","EntityContainerName":"JQGridDBEntities","EntityKeyValues":[{"Key":"ID","Value":5}],"IsTemporary":false}},{"ID":6,"FirstName":"Virendra","LastName":"Sehwag","LastSSN":"114","Department":"Batsman","Age":"36        ","Salary":"8000000   ","Address":"India","MaritalStatus":"Married   ","EntityState":2,"EntityKey":{"EntitySetName":"tbl_Details","EntityContainerName":"JQGridDBEntities","EntityKeyValues":[{"Key":"ID","Value":6}],"IsTemporary":false}},{"ID":7,"FirstName":"Zaheer","LastName":"Khan","LastSSN":"115","Department":"Bowler","Age":"36        ","Salary":"3000000   ","Address":"India","MaritalStatus":"Married   ","EntityState":2,"EntityKey":{"EntitySetName":"tbl_Details","EntityContainerName":"JQGridDBEntities","EntityKeyValues":[{"Key":"ID","Value":7}],"IsTemporary":false}},{"ID":8,"FirstName":"Demo","LastName":"Demo","LastSSN":"Demo","Department":"Demo","Age":"Demo      ","Salary":"Demo      ","Address":"Demo","MaritalStatus":"Demo      ","EntityState":2,"EntityKey":{"EntitySetName":"tbl_Details","EntityContainerName":"JQGridDBEntities","EntityKeyValues":[{"Key":"ID","Value":8}],"IsTemporary":false}},{"ID":9,"FirstName":"Demo","LastName":"Demo","LastSSN":"Demo","Department":"Demo","Age":"Demo      ","Salary":"Demo      ","Address":"Demo","MaritalStatus":"Demo      ","EntityState":2,"EntityKey":{"EntitySetName":"tbl_Details","EntityContainerName":"JQGridDBEntities","EntityKeyValues":[{"Key":"ID","Value":9}],"IsTemporary":false}},{"ID":10,"FirstName":"Demo","LastName":"Demo","LastSSN":"Demo","Department":"Demo","Age":"Demo      ","Salary":"Demo      ","Address":"Demo","MaritalStatus":"Demo      ","EntityState":2,"EntityKey":{"EntitySetName":"tbl_Details","EntityContainerName":"JQGridDBEntities","EntityKeyValues":[{"Key":"ID","Value":10}],"IsTemporary":false}}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are misunderstanding how jqGrid works. If you don't use `loadonce: true` option jqGrid send **automatically** request to `url` with additional parameters which specify the page size and the requested page. So you don't need to many any `$.ajax` and you don't need to bind `$(".ui-pg-input").click`. Default names of 1-based "page number" parameter is `page` and the name of "row size" parameter is `rows`. So you need just rename parameters of `Records` actions.

Alternatively you can use `prmNames` option of jqGrid (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions)) to inform jqGrid to use other parameter names as default `page` and `rows`. For example you can add the option

```
prmNames: {page: "pageNumber", rows: "rowSize"}
```

to solve your problem.

Comment: Actually i don't want to use the following script  $(".ui-pg-input").click(function () { }). I want that each time when i change the page the grid will reload with the data present in the Controller

Comment: @Undefiend: Do you tried my suggestion: either rename parameters of `Records` action (uses `public JsonResult Records(int page=3, int rows = 5)`) or add `prmNames: {page: "pageNumber", rows: "rowSize"}` option of jqGrid? Is the problem is solved now?

Comment: I got the vaule of pageNumber and rowSize in the controller but there is no paging is visible at the bottom now how can i send the new values of pageNumber and row Size to the controller on page change.

Comment: Is it possible to attain custom paging in the JQGrid

Comment: @Undefiend: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. You wrote "there is no paging is visible at the bottom now". I have no idea what you mean. An screenshort could clear all. You wrote "can i send the new values of pageNumber and row Size to the controller on page change" and I don't understand why it is not already because you wrote that the controller get the new values. Ir **the response** on the request are correctly filled? do you set correctly `page`, `total` and `records` fields of [the response](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#json_data)?

Comment: After applying your code, I got the new values in my controller when I Change the rowSize (i.e rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50]) at the runtime which is present at the bottom of grid. This process reload my grid with new data. Like on page load i got 10 row size and got 10 records,then I change the rowsize from 10 to 20 and i got 20 records. But here i only got i.e 10, 20 etc records the value of paging is still not clickable and total records are also equals to the rowSize. So If in my database i have 56 record and rowSize is 20 then there is 20 records in grid(which is correct) but

Comment: paging is not available(which i want to be enable)  and value of total records at the bottom is 20(which i want to be 56).

Comment: @Undefiend: I'm almost sure that the server response contains wrong values of `page`, `total` or `records` properties. jqGrid enable or disable paging buttons based on `page`, `total` values of the server response. Could you append your question with JSON returned from the server?

Comment: @Undefiend: In two previous comments I'v written you about `page`, `total` and `records` which **must exist** in the server response in case of server side paging. I posted [the link](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#json_data) to the documentation which describes the server response. If you would follow the documentation  your problem should be solved.